# Parse xml file - PHP - html tags

Tags: php, xml-parsing, html

#### **SOLVED**: I have used nl2br to reach my aim.

I parse xml file using SofeeXmlParser. The file, among other things, includes descriptions. I need to have some sentences in this descriptions in new line. Is it possible?

The output of such description looks:

```
(
    [value] =>  
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT 

Text text text, text text text text text text.   

 Text text text, text text text text text text.  Text text text, text text text     

 Text text text, text text text text text text.    Text text text, text text text text text text.    Text text text, text text text text text text.   

 TEXT TEXT TEXT.     
  )
```

I put the output of xml file into mysql and then I would like to display it in my website but I would like to have some sentences in new line like in this output.

Comment: Example code ... input ... expected output ... <- these things are all missing from your question - without them it will be very difficult to help ...

Comment: Sorry. I've added the example output.

Comment: Thats even more confusing !!!!!

Comment: It doesn't sound good;-)

Comment: Don't parse HTML with XML. Missing closing tags mess it up. Use DOM

Comment: I'm very sorry. I am not clear. I got the data in xml file. I have to put them into database and then display them. So I parse it using php. I wonder if it is possible to force php to recognize that when some sentence in xml file is in new line it should put for example <br/> before it.

Comment: use `nl2br()` while displaying

Comment: I guess when you use the solution suggested you are suppose to accept the answer.

Comment: I know but I haven't used your solution. I found an answer on my question in PHP manual, but thanks anyway;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `nl2br()` php function to put `<br />` on every new line occurrence

[nl2br php function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Example:

```
echo nl2br($arrayData['value']);
// this will replace all the new line character with <br />
```